# Best practice to use bit operations to set some flags

Tags: objective-c, ios, bit-manipulation

I would like to turn on/off 3 stars that represent a level of difficulty. I don't want to make usage of several if condition, would it be possible to do so by just using bitwise operation?

Let's say i have declared an enum like this:

```
enum 
{
    EASY = 0,
    MODERATE,
    CHALLENGING
} Difficulty;
```

I would like to find a bit operation that let me find which star to turn on or off:

e.g:

```
level 2 (challenging)
star 0 -> 1
star 1 -> 1
star 2 -> 1

level 1 (moderate)
star 0 -> 1
star 1 -> 1
star 2 -> 0

level 0 (easy)
star 0 -> 1
star 1 -> 0
star 2 -> 0
```

Comment: the enum doesn't have to start at 0 if it is easier

Comment: The second star can't be turned on when the first is turned off, so you can just use a Difficulty variable.

Comment: @timjver u mean i don't need to use bitwise operation actually?

Comment: @tiguero why do you need bitwise operations at all? in your case it is just EASY, MODERATE or CHALLENGING, isn't it? But another thing if you want to have one bit per star and have different stars combinations, like 101 or 011 or 110, than yes you neet bits

Comment: @Ezeki Yes you are right, but i have an other case to handle when the order won't matter so i wanted to practice a bit with bitwise operation

Comment: @tiguero take a look at my answer please

Comment: @Ezeki i did i just want to wait a bit to see what people think is the best answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to do something like this:

```
typedef enum Difficulty : NSUInteger
{
    EASY = 1 << 0,
    MODERATE = 1 << 1,
    CHALLENGING = 1 << 2
} Difficulty;
```

And then to check it:

```
- (void) setStarsWithDifficulty:(Difficulty)diff
{
    star0 = (diff & (EASY | MODERATE | CHALLENGING));
    star1 = (diff & (MODERATE | CHALLENGING));
    star2 = (diff & CHALLENGING);
}
```

Comment: I validated this for the simplicity of ur answer

Answer (score 20):

In the case if you want to have 3 bits to save your stars states, like instead of having three boolean flags, than you should do:

```
typedef enum 
{
    DifficultyEasy = 1 << 0,
    DifficultyModerate = 1 << 1,
    DifficultyChallenging = 1 << 2
} Difficulty;

Difficulty state = 0; // default
```

To set Easy:

```
state |= DifficultyEasy;
```

To add Challenging:

```
state |= DifficultyChallenging;
```

To reset Easy:

```
state &= ~DifficultyEasy;
```

To know is Challenging set:

```
BOOL isChallenging =  DifficultyChallenging & state;
```

In the case somebody needs an explanation how it works:

```
1 << x means set x bit to 1 (from right);
// actually it means move 0b00000001 left by x, but I said 'set' to simplify it 

1 << 5 = 0b00100000; 1 << 2 = 0b00000100; 1 << 0 = 0b00000001;

0b00001111 | 0b11000011 = 0b11001111 (0 | 0 = 0, 1 | 0 = 1, 1 | 1 = 1)

0b00001111 & 0b11000011 = 0b00000011 (0 & 0 = 0, 1 & 0 = 0, 1 & 1 = 1)

~0b00001111 = 0b11110000 (~0 = 1, ~1 = 0)
```

Comment: haha =) not at all, i just know that a lot of people don't understand this staff, so maybe they will find it useful later =)

Comment: I know what you mean. :) Luckily (sadly?) opportunities to use this don't come up that often.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about something like:

```
star0 = 1
star1 = value & CHALLENGING || value & MODERATE
star2 = value & CHALLENGING
```

Comment: are u sure it is not | instead of || ?

Comment: Yeah, that's a regular OR expression. It's the same as `value & (MODERATE | CHALLENGING)` from @Tobi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define STAR0 1
#define STAR1 2
#define STAR2 4

#define  EASY   STAR0
#define  MODERATE  STAR1|STAR0
#define  CHALLENGING STAR0|STAR1|STAR2
```

Detection a value d with and and compare against 0 will produce the required mapping, some of the above samples will give you the mapped value instead, take a look:

```
  int d = EASY;
  NSLog(@"Star 0 %d",(d&STAR0)!=0);
  NSLog(@"Star 1 %d",(d&STAR1)!=0);
  NSLog(@"Star 2 %d",(d&STAR2)!=0);
  d=MODERATE;
  NSLog(@"Star 0 %d",(d&STAR0)!=0);
  NSLog(@"Star 1 %d",(d&STAR1)!=0);
  NSLog(@"Star 2 %d",(d&STAR2)!=0);
  d=CHALLENGING;
  NSLog(@"Star 0 %d",(d&STAR0)!=0);
  NSLog(@"Star 1 %d",(d&STAR1)!=0);
  NSLog(@"Star 2 %d",(d&STAR2)!=0);
```

Comment: i hate macro - it is not compiler safe